# Training pretrained object detection models on notebook, not through CLI

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to train an existing model on jupyter notebook from model [zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) e.g. ssd mobilenetv2 coco. Their web page shows how to load and use the models in notebook, but for transfer learning or for training my own annotated images of people, they only provide python [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md)

I tried to find other examples that use jupyter notebook to load the model (object detection models from zoo), but I could only find medium articles referring to the above same script for training.

I know it is possible to load other models in notebook such as [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-using-mobilenet-and-keras-c75daf7ff299), in which we have to freeze initial layers and train the rest of the layers. Is there any notebook or tutorials on how to perform transfer learning on object detection models on jupyter notebook without scripts?

Comment: What is the problem of pasting the scripts contents into Notebook cells? There is notebook for the demo: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb . Just change it according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, Dmytro. The linked page actually shows how to use the pre-trained model in python. However, when it comes to editing the model itself for fine tuning and transfer learning, there is no examples available. But I learned that I can directly access CLI from notebook cells by using ! e.g. !python, which I will do if I don't find examples of how to fine tune object detection models with editing their layers.